# Test a form text_field presence with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, capybara

I have the following form and I want to check if the text field is present or not. How can I do that ?

```rb
<%= form_for(ownership, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.text_field :confirm, value: nil %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :start_date, value: Time.now %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit t('button.ownership.take.confirmation'), class: "btn btn-small"%>
<% end %>
```

Here my test :

```rb
describe "for not confirmed ownership" do

  before do
    FactoryGirl.create(:agreed_ownership, user: current_user, product: product)
    be_signed_in_as(current_user)
    visit current_page
  end

  # it { should_not have_text_field(confirm) }
  it { should_not have_button(t('button.ownership.take.confirmation')) }
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd use a `has_css?` expectation:

```
it "should have the confirm input field" do
  visit current_page

  expect(page).to have_css('input[type="text"]')
end
```

You can use additional jQuery-style selectors to filter for other attributes on the input field, too. For example, `'input[type="text"][name*="confirm"]'` would select for `confirm` appearing in the input field's `name` attribute.

To set an expectation the field *isn't* present, you'd use `to_not` on your expectation: `expect(page).to_not have_css('input[type="text"]')`

**Bonus**: Here's the older, `should`-style syntax:

```
it "should have the confirm input field" do
  visit current_page

  page.should have_css('input[type="text"]')
end

it "shouldn't have the confirm input field" do
  visit current_page

  page.should_not have_css('input[type="text"]')
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! And can you help me with the filling of this field ? Can I do something like `fill_in 'input[type="text"][name="confirm"]', with: "Something"` ?

Comment: For filling the field with [`fill_in`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#fill_in-instance_method), you need to use a "locator," which is a string Capybara checks against the field's `label` text, `name` attribute and `id` attribute. If you don't want to use any of those attributes, you can also do something like `find('input[type="text"][name="confirm"]').set("Something")`, but I'm not a big fan since that syntax feels quite far from how your user would experience/use your application, which is the notional purpose of using Capybara.

Comment: Ok, I tried that but it didn't worked : `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css "input[type=\"text\"][name=\"confirm\"]"`

Comment: Sorry, try the "contains" operator (`*=`) in the second attribute constraint: `find('input[type="text"][name*="confirm"]').set("Something")`